# Java - Code in one file and Design in another file (Unrecognized actionPerformed event)

Tags: java, class, button, class-design

To start sorry for my bad english. I am confronted to a problem. I am creating a new java application and I want to put the design code in a class file named Login_Design.java and de code of the buttons and other content in another class file named Login.java.

The 2 files work like that :

Login_Design.java:

```
    public class Login_Design
    {
        public static JButton jbtnlogin;

        public Login_Design()
        {
            initComponents(); 
        }

    public void initComponents()
    {   
        jframelogin = new JFrame();
        (...)

        jbtnlogin = new JButton();
        (...)

        jbtnlogin.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event)
            {
                Login.jbtnloginActionPerformed(event);
            }
        });

        jframelogin.add(jbtnlogin);
    }
}
```

Login.java:

```
package unigamex;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import unigamex.Login_Design;

public class Login
{
    public Login()
    {
        new Login_Design();
    }

    protected void jbtnloginActionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        new Login();
    }

    public void JActionPerformed()
    {       
        Login_Design.jbtnlogin.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event)
            {
                jbtnloginActionPerformed(event);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now the problem is :
1 - If I put that code in the same java file, all works (all the buttons work)

2 - If I do like i am doing right here, all buttons are showed but it is not possible to use them.

3 - Remove the public void JActionPerformed() and putting the code in the Login_Design 
initcomponents camp, but he shows me the fallowing message :

Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method jbtnsairActionPerformed(ActionEvent) from the type Login

How can i solve that problem ?
Thanks in advance,
Luis Da Costa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to make `Login` implement `ActionListener` and have it register with the `Login_Design` object as such.  The `Login_Design` class would setup any registrants as `ActionListener`s on the buttons.

EDIT:

in `Login_Design`:

```
public void addActionListenerToButtons(ActionListener listener){
    jbtnlongin.addActionListener(listener);
}
```

then in `Login` add `this` to the `Login_Design` instance.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks to your help, I just have a question. As you said to do, I have implemented ActionListener to the login like this : 
public class Login implements ActionListener
But how can i register it in Login_Design as an object ? Create a new public static ActionListerner event and then use it in Login_Design ?
THanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event)             
{                
 Login.jbtnloginActionPerformed(event);             
}
```

You are trying to access a method that can only be accessed via an instance variable (i.e. it is not static).
What you should do is something like the following:

```
public class Login     
{        
  public Login()
  {
     new Login_Design(this);        
  }
   protected void jbtnloginActionPerformed(ActionEvent event)      
   {
       System.exit(0);     
   } 

}



public class Login_Design{ 
  private Login login;
  public Login_Design(Login login){
        this.login = login;
        initComponents();                   
  } 

 public void initComponents()                
 { 
//...
   jbtnlogin = new JButton();                
   jbtnlogin.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
   {
         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event)
         {
             login.jbtnloginActionPerformed(event);

         }

   }
  )
//...
 }

}
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have a problem using your code, because it makes all my buttons do the same :S...

Comment: Just a questions :
Is it a good strategy to create a new file just for design ? Or like netbeans, create a initComponents in the same file and use int it ?

Comment: @user:I have updated my answer.You can now call in each actionListener the appropriate login method you need

Comment: Thank your help !
Before you update you answer I was starting using the e.getSouce() which works very well... but i think it's ugly when using, but i have problems using a switch with events... How can I do that ?... If it is too complicated then i'll use your full code ^^

Comment: You could use `e.getSource()` or `e.getActionCommand()`.With this approach there is a central area that checks which component is checked and calls the appropriate handler in your code.With this approach you can not avoid `switch` or `if` statements, but I think it is ok.Doing like in my post, you associate an anonymous actionListener to each component that is called directly once the component is clicked. So no need to check which button was clicked